# How to connect to remote database from android?

Tags: android, database

I have a website with sql database and i want to connect to the database and make some changes from my android app????

Comment: Just 'cause it has a lot of question marks at the end doesn't make it a question?

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is not nearly enough information here to help you. You need to tell us a lot more about the types of operations you want to perform on the data, what kind of security you require, and a lot more about ... everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely going to need to develop a web service architecture and use the network connection on the android phone to post requests to the website.

You'll have to look into this, nobody is going to just give you all the code you need.

try looking at tutorials like this (using java REST) : 
http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

Comment: Maybe this would be better off as a comment.

Comment: yes it was a bit lacking, added an online resource as a starting point at least